# Why Android BillingClient v2 slow credit card test never cancels?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am implementing the new BillingClient library (v2.1.0) for a non-consumable in-app purchase. 
I am testing pending transactions with a test user. It works fine with "Credit card approves after a few minutes", but with "Slow credit card, rejects after a few minutes" the purchase state is always pending (Waited for hours after it shows as canceled on Play Console).

In order to retrieve purchae status, I am calling to `mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)` as states in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Query-recent)

Has anybody come across this issue before? Is it a development environment problem or does it happen for final users as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here, its probably a bug

Answer (score 6):

I also discovered that in my tests, although I also remember that using the deprecated AIDL a user of my app took 24 hours to validate the purchase. I have considered the case of the refused slow card taking hours may occur and I have done the following:

If `purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING` then I show a dialog that says: *Waiting for purchase validation. Sometimes it can last several hours*

If the user tries to buy the item again and `billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` then I show a dialog that says: *Cannot buy the item. You already own it or a previous purchase is still pending for validation*

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. On `launchBillingFlow` you get a `BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`. the purchase returns `PurchaseState.PENDING`. If you `consumeAsync` immediately after, its response is `BillingResponseCode.DEVELOPER_ERROR`, but after a few minutes (or whatever delay the transaction takes to fail) you can `consumeAsync` again then it returns `BillingResponseCode.ITEM_NOT_OWNED`, now you are allowed to retry the `launchBillingFlow` again. like **Lluis Felisart** said create a dialog to ask the user to clear the pending,

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to consume the purchase on a non-consumable item if the purchase is still pending. Theoretically, you can consume a purchased non-consumable item this way if the timing is just right.

Answer (score 1):

It actually declines a few minutes later. I realized that if you check "Order management" on Play Console you'll see it already declined.

The issue is the local cache of google play billing. I guess that updating this cache for billing tests is very low priority, you can clear it like this:

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
```