# Android BillingClient purchase with "Slow test card. declines after a few minutes" stays PENDING

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

Following the latest Google [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#pending) I have implemented in app purchases.
I have correctly implemented the a [setListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.Builder#setListener(com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener)) so that any purchase updates are correctly received.

During testing, following Androids guidelines, I can make a purchase with different test cards (payment methods) : [image]

When I select to make a payment with the card "Slow test card. Declines after a few minutes". I correctly get a update (via the `setListener`) with a status of `PENDING`.

However, I never get any other update, to signal that the purchase was cancelled (after a few minutes). I left the app open for hours, closed it, restarted. Nothing comes in.
What is the expected behaviour? Is this normal?

Comment: My answer some months ago : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59480042/7690376

Comment: Oh I did not see that during me searches. I will close thus question as duplicate!